# Tocar um aúdio por vez

Tags: html5-audio

Tenho esse cenário:

```
<audio id="audio1" controls>
    <source src="http://stream?type=.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio><br />

<audio id="audio2" controls>
    <source src="http://stream?type=.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio><br />
```

Se der play nos dois tocam ao mesmo tempo. Como configurar pra tocar um por vez.

Comment: Não carregou nenhuma imagem, poderia colocar o HTML?

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou cada uma independente, muda o SRC DO áudio para SRC="http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3"

Comment: São dois audios numa mesma página. Se der o play nos dois, eles vão tocar simultaneamente e eu não queria q ocorresse isso.

Comment: @AllanConservaJr. e o que é que você quer que aconteça se a pessoa der play nos dois?

Answer (score 3):

Acho que seria melhor manter um player e usar uma função javascript para alterar o src e executar, assim você pode ter quantos sons quiser sem ter que se preocupar em ficar controlado a execução de vários players.

Segue um exemplo bem simples.

```js
var tocar = function(url){
  $("#audioPlayer").attr('src',url);   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audioPlayer" controls autoplay></audio>
<br>
<button onclick="tocar('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3');">Horse.mp3</button>
<button onclick="tocar('http://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.ogg');">Horse.ogg</button>
<button onclick="tocar('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg');">Exemple.ogg</button>
<button onclick="tocar('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg');">ACDC.ogg</button>
```

Comment: Black in Black +1

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas você pode realizar esse controle via Jquery.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#audio1").on('click', function(){
    var pe = $("#audio2").get(0); 
    if(pe.paused == false)
      pe.pause();
  });
  $("#audio2").on('click', function(){
    var pe = $("#audio1").get(0); 
    if(pe.paused == false)
      pe.pause();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
 <audio id="audio1" controls>
     <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
 </audio><br />

 <audio id="audio2" controls>
     <source src="http://w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
 </audio><br />
</body>
</html>
```